# Local numbering of the nodes and transformation from a reference triangle in finite element methods

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangulation, finite-element-method

Let

- $\hat K\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be the triangle spanned by $\hat v_1:=(0,0)$, $\hat v_2:=(1,0)$ and $\hat v_3:=(0,1)$
- $K\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be a nondegenerate triangle spanned by $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$
- $T:\hat K\to K$ with $T(\hat K)=K$

Please consider the ordering of vertices on $\partial\hat K$ depicted in the following figure:
[image]

Which assumptions on $T$ do I need to impose in order to ensure that the ordering is preserved in the transformation of $\hat K$ into $K$?

For example, in the figure above, $T_m$ preserves the ordering while $T_m'$ does not.

Clearly, we want that $T$ is of the form $$T(x)=Ax+b\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\hat K\tag1$$ for some invertible $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ and $b\in\mathbb R^2$. Since we need to have $$T(\hat v_i)=v_i\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\left\{1,2,3\right\}\tag2\;,$$ we obtain $$b=v_1\tag3$$ and $$A=\underbrace{\left(v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1\right)}_{\text{columns}}\;.\tag4$$

> So, $T$ is already uniquely determined by the vertices. So, I guess my question shouldn't be how we need to restrict $T$. The question should be how we need to restrict the numbering of further nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep straight lines straight, then your map is affine and preserves the order of points at the line.